# How to install WTForms? Gettiing import error when trying to import forms

Tags: python, flask, pip, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to follow the [Flask Mega Tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) for which I need to use WTForms. As is suggested in the tutorial, I use a virtualenv in which I installed WTForms like this:

```
flask/bin/pip install flask-wtf
```

This seemed to work fine, and when I now run it again I simply get this:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): flask-wtf in ./flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask in ./flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask-wtf)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): WTForms>=1.0 in ./flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask-wtf)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Werkzeug>=0.7 in ./flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask->flask-wtf)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Jinja2>=2.4 in ./flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask->flask-wtf)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): itsdangerous>=0.21 in ./flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask->flask-wtf)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): markupsafe in ./flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->Flask->flask-wtf)
Cleaning up...
```

But when I try to import forms using `from forms import LoginForm` I get an error saying: `ImportError: cannot import name LoginForm`.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here, and how I can solve this? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a module named `forms` that contains `LoginForm`,

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import Required

class LoginForm(Form):
    openid = TextField('openid', validators = [Required()])
    remember_me = BooleanField('remember_me', default = False)
```

This is the example taken from [Part iii](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms).

Comment: Stupid stupid me. I did create that file and pasted the code in, I just didn't save the file yet. Excuse me for bothering you guys, and thanks for answering.

Comment: How does this `Form` class compare with
`from flask_wtf  import FlaskForm`. I thought I came across this usage from one of Miguel Grinberg's pycon talks.